# Feeding config into SSH via pipe

Tags: ssh

I need to make individual `ssh` connection configuration dynamic. Ideally it should work as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh -F <(config_provider_command) hostname
```

Many `Linux` and `GNU` commands would gladly consume a pipe instead of a file, but not `ssh` (`openssh`). It errors out complaining there is no such file.

If anyone else had a similar problem to solve I'd very appreciate tips and hints